# preg_match for preventing injection in PHP form

Tags: php, validation, preg-match, contact-form

I am an absolute beginner with PHP, trying to set up a validation to stop header injection on a contact form. I've read a lot of tutorials, and made a form that should validate, but it's not working... after researching a little here it seems my problem is that the code I have uses eregi (old tutorial), which should be preg_match these days. I have used preg_match to validate the email address format, but I want to make sure no line breaks, cc, bcc etc can be snuck in anywhere.
This is the function I have now:

```
    function spamcheck($field) {
if(eregi("to:",$field) || eregi("cc:",$field) || eregi("Content-Type:",$field) || eregi("bcc:",$field) || eregi("%0D",$field) || eregi("\r",$field) || eregi("\n",$field) || eregi("%0A",$field)){ 
    $possiblespam = TRUE;
}else $possiblespam = FALSE;
if ($possiblespam) {
    die("Possible spam attempt detected. If this is not the case, please edit the content of the contact form and try again.");
    return 1;
}
```

}

Now, I'm not sure if I could just replace eregi with preg_match like so:

```
     if(preg_match("/to:/i",$field) 
     // and so on for each string I want to catch
```

I have read here that preg_match needs delimiters, not sure if I've used them right. Also, should be case sensitive, so I added the i flag (without confidence). Still, no real idea if above would actually be correct. Does that seem secure? Again, apologies for my lack of PHP knowledge. This kind of function is quite common in online tutorials, but using eregi rather than preg_match.

Answer (score 0):

Just checking for line breaks should be enough:

```
$possiblespam = (0 !== preg_match("~(\r|\n)~", $field));
```